# osquery custom table issue of deregistering extension

Tags: osquery

using osquery Go binding to create custom table on Windows. acls for extension folder are set as suggested in docs.

when I run following in admin command prompt:
osqueryi --extension c:\osqtst\custable.exe --socket "\.\pipe\shell.em"

i get called in my extension but see following error for server.Run():
"deregistering extension: deregisterExtension: wrong method name"

any clue what's the issue here?